# Getting SSL certificate from remote server with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2

I encountered a strange problem and I cannot spin my head around it. 
I'm trying to validate a SSL certificate using OpenSSL from command line:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.org:443
```

But no matter which domain on this server I call that way it delivers always the certificate of the first (alphabetically) domain on that server even if this particular domain do have own certificate. Also when I call any of this urls in browser everything works correctly

Any idea what have I done wrong?

Regards,
Radek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using an older version of openssl, i.e. version 1.0.2 or lower. With these you have to explicitly use the `-servername` option so that the SNI extension is used to announce the expected hostname in the TLS handshake:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

With later versions of openssl this option is enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it of course.